# Запись считанной строки из консоли в enum

Tags: c#, enum

Возможно ли считанную с консоли строку добавить в enum в кач-ве его нового элемента во время run-time в C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, модифицировать типы в рантайме нельзя (т.е. например, добавлять в типы поля, методы и т.п.). Но можно создавать новые типы, используя классы из `System.Reflection.Emit`. В частности, для создания перечисления можно использовать [`EnumBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Но, к сожалению, такие типы не могут замещать уже существующие.

В вашем случае я бы рассмотрел возможность использования `Dictionary` вместо перечисления.